# Not executing postgresql query on remote machine with ssh

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, ssh, sh

I am facing problem with executing postgresql queries on remote machine from local.

Shell script which I am running on local machine:

```
[postgres@local:~]$ cat main.sh
#!/bin/bash
REMOTE="postgres@192.168.1.200"
PKEY="/home/postgres/pr-key.ppk"
SCRIPT_LOCATION=/home/postgres/scripts
CRONLOG_LOCATION=/home/postgres/project/cronlogs
PGBIN=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin
PGUSER=postgres
PGDATA=/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
PGDATABASE=postgres
PGPORT=5432
PGHOST=192.168.1.200
BLOG=/home/postgres/blogfile
query=`ssh -i $PKEY $REMOTE $PGBIN/psql -U $PGUSER -h $PGHOST -p $PGPORT -d $PGDATABASE -Atc "select datname from pg_database where datname not in ('template0','template1');"`
echo $query
```

Execution:

```
[postgres@local:~]$ ./main.sh
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/psql -U postgres -h 192.168.1.200 -p 5432 -d postgres -Atc select datname from pg_database where datname not in ('template0','template1');'
```

Comment: query isn't quoted after interpretation, take a look on last line of output `bash: -c:... -Atc select datname...`

Comment: even if i quote, still i am facing problem. Kindly let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Why are you assigning results to `query` and then expanding that variable unquoted? Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: @SivaKrishna can you post fixed code&error(or is it same error)? can you run script in debug mode (with `-x` flag) and post last lines? why via `ssh`(postgres available only on local machine)?

Comment: @SivaKrishna try to enclose query with single quotes, i.e. `-Atc '"select ...('template0','template1');"'`

Comment: @sKwa, Please find attached debug info.

Comment: @sKwa, Below is debut info.
[postgres@local:~]$ sh -x main.sh
+ BLOG=/home/postgres/blogfile
++ ssh -i /home/postgres/pr-key.ppk postgres@192.168.1.200 /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/psql -U postgres -h 192.168.1.200 -p 5432 -d postgres -Atc ' "select datname from pg_database where datname not in (template0,template1);" '
ERROR:  column "template0" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ct datname from pg_database where datname not in (template0,...
      + query=
+ echo
debug code is displaying (template0,template1) insted of this ('template0','template1') . 
thanks in advance

Comment: @SivaKrishna okay, problem is in quotes, now it do query against a db, as you can see: `ERROR: column "template0" does not exist`. I will post a final solution later or may be someone else will post a solution.

Answer (score 1):

ssh allows you run a script file stored on the ssh client that runs on the remote machine as if it was actually on the remote machine, which makes the scripting easier. If you can get you progree.sql.sh file to work in the local context then

```
ssh user@hostname 'bash -s' < sql.script_on_this_machine.sh
```

I use keys so I don't have to worry about passwords here.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, if i create sql file on remote machine and give input to ssh along with psql then this is working. as i have caveats, remote server is production. i should not create any kind of file . all Variable values mentioned on above script(sample) will change dynamically and i understood and did r&d i have only problem with single quotes(') and double quotes(""). is there any solution without creating file on remote server. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SivaKrishna, the code in this answer does not require the script to be remote. The suggestion is that instead of having the script run `ssh -i ...` itself, you use `ssh` to invoke an interpreter on the remote system, and feed it script text to execute on stdin.

Comment: @Charles, Thank you for suggestion. the code which i pasted above is 
Sample And script has ssh commands in side like above. As sKwa suggested code is working now. Thank you very much for spending your time.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought the problem in quotes and `bash` string's interpretation with quotes.

Try next:

```
...
QUERY='"select datname from pg_database where datname not in ('\'template0\'', '\'template1\'');"'
RESULT=$(ssh ... -Atc "${QUERY}")
echo "${RESULT}"
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfectly working,  i did small change, i.e  RESULT=$(ssh ... -Atc ${QUERY}). with $"{QUERY}" it is not working means throwing error. Any how. Could you please give small info on this line QUERY='"select datname from pg_database where datname not in ('\'template0\'', '\'template1\'');"'. because i did understand with double quotes inside single quotes and '\' and \''.  Once again thank you for providing solution.

Comment: i did not *, typo

Comment: @SivaKrishna, typo should be "${QUERY}"(sorry), about quotes I will update answer later.